# Entity Framework - Table-Valued Functions - Parameter Already Exists

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I am using table-valued functions with Entity Framework 5. I just received this error:

> A parameter named 'EffectiveDate' already exists in the parameter collection. Parameter names must be unique in the parameter collection. Parameter name: parameter

It is being caused by me joining the calls to table-valued functions taking the same parameter.

Is this a bug/limitation with EF? Is there a workaround? Right now I am auto-generating the code (.edmx file).

Answer (score 11):

It would be really nice if Microsoft would make parameter names unique, at least on a per-context basis.

I've created an issue for this [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2028).

In the meantime, I was able to get this to work by tweaking a few functions in the .Context.tt file, so that it adds a GUID to each parameter name at runtime:

```
private void WriteFunctionImport(TypeMapper typeMapper, CodeStringGenerator codeStringGenerator, EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption) {
    if (typeMapper.IsComposable(edmFunction))
    {
#>

    [EdmFunction("<#=edmFunction.NamespaceName#>", "<#=edmFunction.Name#>")]
    <#=codeStringGenerator.ComposableFunctionMethod(edmFunction, modelNamespace)#>
    {       var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"); <#+
        codeStringGenerator.WriteFunctionParameters(edmFunction, " + guid", WriteFunctionParameter);
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.ComposableCreateQuery(edmFunction, modelNamespace)#>
    } <#+
    }
    else
    {
#>

    <#=codeStringGenerator.FunctionMethod(edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption)#>
    { <#+
        codeStringGenerator.WriteFunctionParameters(edmFunction, "", WriteFunctionParameter);
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.ExecuteFunction(edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption)#>
    } <#+
        if (typeMapper.GenerateMergeOptionFunction(edmFunction, includeMergeOption))
        {
            WriteFunctionImport(typeMapper, codeStringGenerator, edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption: true);
        }
    } }
```

...

```
public void WriteFunctionParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction, string nameSuffix, Action<string, string, string, string> writeParameter)
{
    var parameters = FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
    foreach (var parameter in parameters.Where(p => p.NeedsLocalVariable))
    {
        var isNotNull = parameter.IsNullableOfT ? parameter.FunctionParameterName + ".HasValue" : parameter.FunctionParameterName + " != null";
        var notNullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\"" + nameSuffix + ", " + parameter.FunctionParameterName + ")";
        var nullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\"" + nameSuffix + ", typeof(" + parameter.RawClrTypeName + "))";
        writeParameter(parameter.LocalVariableName, isNotNull, notNullInit, nullInit);
    }
}
```

...

```
public string ComposableCreateQuery(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
{
    var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<{0}>(\"[{1}].[{2}]({3})\"{4});",
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
        edmFunction.NamespaceName,
        edmFunction.Name,
        string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.EsqlParameterName + "\" + guid + \"").ToArray()),
        _code.StringBefore(", ", string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. Maybe a limitation or an omission. Apparently this use case has never been taken into account. EF *could* use auto-created parameter names, but, yeah, it just doesn't.

You'll have to resort to calling one of the functions with `.AsEnumerable()`. For some reason, this must be the first function in the join (as I have experienced). If you call the second function with `.AsEnumerable()` it is still translated to SQL and the name collision still occurs.